# Updating Controller and Views after adding column to Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to Entity framework, so this is probably a stupid question.

I have added a new field to a Model class. I have created the migration and updated the database and this all works as expected. The new column has appeared in the SQL table.

I have manually modified the Create/Details Views (I'm guessing this isn't automatic) to include the new column. The new column is called "Level".

However, my Controller class doesn't seem to have picked up the changes. It doesn't insert the value when creating a new row. There are references to column names in the Controller class, but the new column name isn't there. E.g.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name")] Course course)
```

Is there any way to "refresh" the Controller to pick up the changes? Or will I have to manually edit the lines where the columns are named and add the new column?

Answer (score 1):

If your view has a control bound to this new Level field and you want to pass it to the controller to write, then you will need to add it to the `Bind` attribute:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Level")] Course course)
```

While it might look like when you pass a Model to a view, and have a Form in the view that calls an action on the Controller passing that Model back, this isn't actually what happens. ASP.Net MVC is merely formatting the code in that way. Honestly this is a bit of a bad practice when using EF Entities as it trips up quite a few developers expecting that Entity references are being passed between server and view. It leads to confusing problems and is also an open door to data tampering when used incorrectly.

When the controller passes the Model to the `View()`, it is passing that Model to the View Renderer to compose the HTML view that will be sent to the browser. So  if you're passing a Course entity, that entity does *not* travel to the client, it is consumed by the Server to build the HTML.

When your Form goes to call the controller, it will automatically append any bound fields that it knows about. This will include any bound entry controls, and if there are any details that don't have edit controls bound to them, you need to use bound Hidden controls to ensure that the MVC Javascript knows to pick those up too.

If you use a `Bind` attribute, this tells MVC which properties coming back from a Form submit or Ajax call that you actually want to accept. If "Level" isn't in there, the value will be ignored even if passed. The View does not pass an actual entity, it will be a set of named parameters that MVC has some magic smarts to convert into a Model object based on convention.

The Action could be written as either:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Level")] Course course)
```

or

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int id, string name, string level)
```

where in the second case you'd need to handle the creation and population of your Course entity using the values passed in.

Comment: This is a very good explanation and answered a few other questions I had. Thank you for your help.